# What does "a given" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The island is located in the Baltic Sea. There are lots of things to
>   do in this island, and a seaside setting is **a given**.

The meaning found in a dictionary was "a known or established fact or situation", but it doesn't fit in this context. Does it mean that "seaside setting is naturally gifted/so good"? or does it mean that "seaside setting is a must-see"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does mean what the dictionary is saying in that context. The author is talking about being on an island. When you are on a small island you know the sea will be nearby. It's a given.

Comment: The expression was common in geometry problems when I was at school. "Given that two angles of a triangle are 90 and 30 degrees, state the third angle". Given that a place is an island, the sea must be nearby, although the inhabitants of Coton in the Elms, in Derbyshire, might argue, since the nearest sea is 70 miles away.